# Unit testing services annotations without Symfony

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, yaml

I got a few bundles that are not installed in `Symfony` yet.

These bundles have a `services.yml` file in them:

```
mybundle/src/Bundle/Resources/config/services.yml
```

The `services.yml` contains classes and arguments from the bundle that are later used by `Symfony`, but not by the bundle itself:

```
mybundle.data.download.get:
  class: mybundle\data\download\getinfo\get
  arguments:
  - "@bundle.myDepdendency.generate"
  - "@bundle.myDepdendency.dosomething"
  - "@bundle.helloThere"
```

I have working unit tests in `Symfony` for `services.yml` that checks that all classes are loaded correctly, however since I am developing the bundles independently outside of Symfony, I'd like to have a test to know if `services.yml` contains all the classes and their arguments.

So the question is:

Is there a way to test if `services.yml` contains given classes and their arguments without using Symfony?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with this snippet:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;

$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($containerBuilder, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../BundlePath/Resources/config'));
$loader->load('services.yml');
$containerBuilder->compile();
```

Of course you need the symfony/dependency-injection and symfony/config components of symfony. But here you would test if any exception will thrown. If not, then every service was found and could be wired.

With

```
$containerBuilder->get('service_id') instanceof Bundle\Service\SomeService
```

you can even test if the service class was realy loaded.